# Android on Copay still available?

Tags: wallet, android, copay

Hi I was downloading Copay and it said ;

> #### WARNING: Chrome App will not longer be supported
>
> Google has announced that it will be ending support for Chrome Apps on non-Chrome OS platforms in 2018. This means that our Copay bitcoin wallet will no longer be available. Please use other Copay platform. If you are using a hardware wallet, we recommend that you move your funds to other wallet as soon as possible.

I was wondering if it is okay to download from google store and use or if I should just use the wallet on another platform?

Answer (score -1):

Android apps are unaffected by this change.